# Using 2 arrays, layout not correct

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
    document.getElementById("task").innerHTML="Task 8";
    var arrNames = [];
    var arrToys = [];
    var vName = "";
    var vToys = "";
    vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
    vToys = prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)");
    while (vName.length > 0) {
        arrNames.push(vName);
        arrToys.push(vToys);
        vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
        vToys = prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)");
    }
    var vOutput = "Dog names and No. of toys: <br/>" + arrNames.map((name, i) => `Dog ${i + 1} Name: ${name}`).join("<br/>") + arrToys.map((name) => `   No. of Toys: ${name}`).join("<br/>");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=vOutput;
}
```

When I run the code I get the name of the dog but then the number of toys is under the dogs names, how do I get the number of toys next to the dogs name?
Thank you

Comment: use a loop,that loops through both arrays together or use two adjacent div elements or use two table cells.

Comment: Not sure how to do that

Comment: You only have `arrNames` displayed at output not `arrToys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This puts the output in a table with two columns and a table header row.

```
var vOutput = "<table><tr><th colspan=\"2\">Dog names and No. of toys:</th></tr><tr><td>" + arrNames.map((name, i) => `Dog ${i + 1} Name: ${name}`).join("<br/>") + "</td><td>" + arrToys.map((name) => `   No. of Toys: ${name}`).join("<br/>") + "</td></tr></table>";
```

This is the simplest way to do it but it will only work if both sides use one line each per dog.